# torrent program dropping peers

Tags: bittorrent

i am trying to download a torrent and i'm noticing that i have plenty of seeds and peers, but the peers connect then disconnect very quickly after, they keep getting dropped.

why could this be? firewall settings possibly?

Comment: Which client are you using?

Comment: utorrent [15 chars]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause is probably that whatever ports your torrent client requires are not not being allowed / forwarded by your firewall. Check the documentation for your client to see what UDP/TCP ports it needs and open them up / forward them to the machine running the torrent client.

There's [a guide to opening ports for uTorrent](http://www.lostintechnology.com/how-to/guide-to-opening-ports-for-utorrent-and-azureus) which might help?

There's a setting in uTorrent which allows you to always use a particular port. If you set that and then forward the port on your firewall, you should see the icon at the bottom of the window turn green indicating other people can connect to you. There's also a connection setting tester built into uTorrent so you can test the port settings.

It's probably worth having a read through [the uTorrent documentation](http://www.utorrent.com/documentation/connection-setup) too.

Comment: This seems unlikely to me. If the problem was port forwarding, the peers wouldn't be able to connect at all.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same thing. Every 10-20 seconds all seeders disappeared. And then miraculously re-appeared.
Then my computer was so friendly to tell me my drive was almost full.
After deleting some obsolete files all torrents/connections/seeders/speeds were fine.

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem - the solution is to clear disk space.